# Create JSON object from a String receive from Server

Tags: java, json

I want to create JSON object from JSON data receive from server as A String.

I receive following JSON data from server to String "practiceInfoByUsername"

```
{
    "method_name": "getMyPracticeInfo",
    "module_name": "pciLoc",
    "result_set": [
        {
            "practice_address": {
                "state_province": "GA",
                "_types": [
                    "Address"
                ],
                "county_district": "",
                "address1": "1111 Test Street",
                "address2": "",
                "city_village": "Atlanta",
                "longitude": "",
                "subregion": "",
                "postal_code": "00000",
                "township_division": "",
                "country": "USA",
                "latitude": "",
                "region": "",
                "_cls": "Address"
            },
            "ucf_fee_group_id": 0,
            "practice_type": "H",
            "practice_website": "",
            "insurance_plan_fee_group_id": 0,
            "practice_edi_vendor_id": "",
            "practice_comments": "",
            "practice_date_changed": "2011-10-14 17:48:14",
            "practice_entity_id": "E01",
            "practice_pref_use_metric": true,
            "practice_changed_by": "",
            "practice_message_on_patient_statement": "",
            "practice_fax": "",
            "practice_def_birth_year": 1930,
            "practice_id": "P01",
            "practice_ein": "",
            "practice_npi": "",
            "practice_phone": "",
            "practice_email": "",
            "practice_name": "Test Practice #1",
            "practice_depts": [
                {
                    "d_name": "Accident and emergency",
                    "d_type": "AE",
                    "d_code": "EMER",
                    "d_notes": ""
                },
                {
                    "d_name": "Cardiology",
                    "d_type": "CA",
                    "d_code": "CARD",
                    "d_notes": ""
                },
                {
                    "d_name": "Diagnostic imaging",
                    "d_type": "DI",
                    "d_code": "DIAG",
                    "d_notes": ""
                },
                {
                    "d_name": "Obstetrics and gynaecology",
                    "d_type": "OB",
                    "d_code": "OBG",
                    "d_notes": ""
                }
            ]
        }
    ],
    "rec_count": 1
}
```

I have Use following Code for create JSON object

JSONObject JSO = new JSONObject(practiceInfoByUsername);

But it is mark as wrong in Netbeans my String name "practiceInfoByUsername" underline in red colour

I think I have mistake in configuring JSON library for Netbeans

please help me

Comment: Paste part of your source. What's the error in NB? Maybe it's just a spelling info. Turn off spelling check in NB.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The code should be

```
import net.sf.json.JSONObject;
JSONObject JSO = JSONObject.fromObject(practiceInfoByUsername);
```

Also you need json-lib jar, can be downloaded [here](http://json-lib.sourceforge.net/).

Comment: Thank you, It is work, Please Help me get values from That JSON object

Comment: JSO.getBoolean(key) == value

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend you to use a library for json .. there are plenty of them.
The most used (from what I know), is [google-gson](http://code.google.com/p/google-gson/) .. good documentation and examples along the web also ..

You can also take a look [here](http://www.rojotek.com/blog/2009/05/07/a-review-of-5-java-json-libraries/) .. for an overview of the JSON-tools.